# How to configure a makefile?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, compilation

I wanted to compile glibc source code.so I used "make && make install" command but it gave an error that I first need to configure it and I don't know how to configure it.so how to configure that makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the command ./configure first.  This will configure the makefile.

However, it would really be helpful first to read the README file that is in whatever package you are trying to make.  They will (or should) have examples on how to install the package.

For example, usually ./configure will take options.. like where you want the package installed, or using a specific compiler or library options.